# Compare rows with matching ids to identify which rows and which fields in each row differ between two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm helping to migrate away from a legacy database and need to identify changes made since we last dumped the legacy database.

The table in question has (no joke) a few hundred columns, but only a few thousand rows. What I want to do is compare the rows in table_old with the rows in table_new, matching on thing_id, then for each row containing different values in any field, return the thing_id and  column name for the differences.

My problem is answers like [Comparing rows in table for differences between fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480347/comparing-rows-in-table-for-differences-between-fields) and [How to compare two rows or get the fields which value is not match with the rows that compared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698087/how-to-compare-two-rows-or-get-the-fields-which-value-is-not-match-with-the-rows) are oriented towards comparing specific fields between the two tables, whereas I want to compare all fields.

Is this just a bridge too far for mysql? I've tried tools like navicat and while it will show me schema differences and synchronize data differences and show me which rows contained data differences, it won't identify which columns in a given row differed.

Note table_new has 37 more rows than table_old. Table schema is identical, as of course are column names.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem with a neat SQL solution, but off the top of my head, if you're not expecting huge amounts of differences, your best bet might just be to extract the data as csv ordered by thing_id, and compare in a text comparison tool (beyond compare, winmerge, notepad++ compare plugin). This will very quickly tell you at least which rows (or how many rows) have differences. I will watch this question though in case someone comes up with a more  elegant solution as I have often needed something like this :)

Comment: Hmmm, that might well be the best solution...